# JavaFX-Passing value between fxml and update listview

Tags: listview, javafx

I have a scene contain a **hbox(root) with 2 vboxes**, each vbox contain **seperate fxml files and controllers**. 1st vbox contains a button and textfield,and 2nd one contain a listview,So what I need is when I click the button value on textfield should be passed to listview and update without loading a new stage thats all.
**Note**: I found a working solution by using

`fx:include id="v1"` as vbox children

in fxml and init the controllers in main controller, but sadly later if I want replace the vbox children with
new fxml means, what will I do? So any simple working solutions?

Here is my maincontroller.java

```
public class MainController implements Initializable{
    @FXML
    private VBox v1;

    @FXML
    private VBox v2;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        try {
            v1.getChildren().add(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("voneFX.fxml")));
            v2.getChildren().add(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("vtwoFX.fxml")));
          } catch (IOException ex) {
              Logger.getLogger(FXMLDocumentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
          }
     }
}
```

voneController.java

```
public class voneController  {

    @FXML private TextField txt1;
    @FXML private Button btn1Send;

    @FXML private void btn1SendClicked(ActionEvent event){
        //Here i would like to call updateListView method
    }
}
```

votwoController.java

```
public class vtwoController{

     @FXML
    private ListView<ListModel> sampleListview;
    ObservableList<ListModel> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList ();

    public void updateListView() {
      //This is the method which is called when user hit the button.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make what you want, you need to have access to the controllers (the controllers themselves must be able to communicate with each other). `FXMLLoader` offers several options for accessing controllers. The first option is to automatically inject the fxml components included with the `include` in the fxml file.

```
<fx:include fx:id="childView" source="child.fxml"/>
```

In order for the controller to be injected, a field of the controller type specified in `child.fxml` must be declared with the name specified in `fx:id` with suffix Controller. And of course, annotate with `@FXML`.

```
public class MainController {
    @FXML
    private ChildController childViewController;

    ...
}
```

If you are going to be working with a dynamically changing context, you can manually create the controller and pass it on to `FXMLLoader`, which will initialize it by injecting the appropriate fields or simply picking up the initialized instance.

Here, it's important to first call `FXMLLoader#load()`, and then `FXMLLoader#getController()`.

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/resource/layout/child.fxml"));
Parent parent = loader.load();

ChildController controller = loader.getController();
```

When manually creating the controller, you must first call `FXMLLoader#setController()` and then `FXMLLoader#load()`.

```
ChildController controller = new ChildController();

FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/resource/layout/child.fxml"));
loader.setController(controller);
Parent parent = loader.load();
```

Consequently, communication between controllers is trivial and I do not think there is a need to explain.

**UPDATE**

An example of how communication is made between objects.
These are the two views that use the app:

child.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>

<HBox alignment="CENTER_LEFT" spacing="5.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.ChildController">
   <children>
      <Label text="Child View" />
      <TextField fx:id="textField" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
      <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Send to parent" onAction="#handleSendButton"/>
   </children>
</HBox>
```

sample.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<VBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" spacing="5.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.MainController">
   <children>
      <HBox spacing="5.0">
         <children>
            <TextField fx:id="textField" editable="false" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Refresh" onAction="#handleRefreshButton"/>
         </children>
      </HBox>
      <HBox fx:id="childContainer">
         <fx:include fx:id="childView" source="child.fxml" />
      </HBox>
   </children>
</VBox>
```

And respectively the two controllers.

```
public class ChildController {

    @FXML
    private TextField textField;

    private Consumer<String> consumer;

    public void addConsumer(Consumer<String> consumer) {
        this.consumer = consumer;
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleSendButton(ActionEvent event) {
        if(consumer == null) {
            return;
        }

        consumer.accept(textField.getText());
    }

}
```

Here, pressing the Refresh button reloads the inserted view.

```
public class MainController {
    @FXML
    private TextField textField;

    @FXML
    private HBox childContainer;

    @FXML
    private ChildController childViewController;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        childViewController.addConsumer(textField::setText);
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleRefreshButton(ActionEvent event) {
        try {
            textField.setText("");

            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("child.fxml"));
            Parent parent = loader.load();

            childViewController = loader.getController();
            childViewController.addConsumer(textField::setText);

            childContainer.getChildren().setAll(parent);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay, i have tried 3 methods as you said,1)using fx:include,but what is the problem is later i want to replace it with new fxml so how i can do that?

Comment: 2)using getcontroller, problem: we need to set into a stage ,or may refresh the scene

Comment: ues `v1.getChildren().add(parent);` to change context  and keep controler.

Comment: You can also use the 4th option that relies on the `fx:root` statement. But it is more complex and is more used to create custom controls.

Comment: ok as you said i just defined them in main controller,like this ChildController controller = new ChildController();

FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/resource/layout/child.fxml"));
loader.setController(controller);
Parent parent = loader.load();v1.getChildren().add(parent);,then what should i do in vone controller to call the method in vtwocontroller

Comment: This already concerns the communication between objects. It is simplest to declare public methods that controllers call each other. You can add callback notifications and whatever you think you need.

Comment: but iam getting null pointer exception when call a the method helloworld in vtwocontroller,from vone controller,i called like this-> vtwoController vc=new vtwoController();
         vc.helloworld();

Comment: and the method looks like this public void helloworld() {
    System.out.println("helloworld");
    lbl2.setText("hai");
},here getting error when try to update label,and system.out works correctly

Comment: Actually this is the place(when button press-listview update)where iam stucked for a week,so expecting answer related to that.Thankyou

Comment: Look at the editorial. I have set an example of how communication between objects in the OOP is realized.

Comment: i got and understood ur update,but u stiil did'nt get my need,here the child is allocated with fx:include tag,so in future we cannot replace it another fxml right?if yes please tell me,and second thing is you are loading the content by reloading when click the button right?

Comment: And 3rd thing is you are passing the datas between main controller and child,but in my case the communication happening between 2 childs under a parent.

Comment: The FXML file is parsed one time. Subsequently, all parts of the generated view can be replaced. For the replacement is not important the include statement. The container in which it is located is important (in the case of HBox). When you have access to the container you can replace / add whatever you want in it.
And whether to make communication between child and parrent controller or between child and child is the same. These are just two objects. Even if you wish. you can inject them into one another.